# Inspite of the fact

Tags: phrase-usage

Imagine the following piece of conversation:

> -- You had not been prepared to the exam.
>
> -- Inspite of that fact I've passed it excellent.

Does it make sense? I'm not sure about the last sentence, the expression `Inspite of ...`. Is it common in such situations? I suspect that there is a more common phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Accusation:** *"You were not prepared for the exam"*
>
> **Response:** *"In spite of that fact, I passed with excellent scores."*

Notes: *"in spite"* is two words.  One is prepared *for* an exam, not *to* an exam.

It is a common expression, and it does make sense (as adjusted).  Another way to respond would be *I passed with excellent scores anyway.*